# Which implementation of Salsa20 should I use?

Tags: encryption, windows, c

I would like to use a secure stream cipher algorithm for my application as RC4 is know to have multiple vulnerabilities, I turn myself toward Salsa20.

OpenSSL is my reference for cryptographic algorithms implementation but this time I can't see anything [related to Salsa20 on their website](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aopenssl.org%20salsa20).

Where can I find a **trustable** implementation in C of the Salsa20 stream cipher ?

Comment: https://nacl.cr.yp.to/stream.html, https://github.com/everard/Salsa20, https://github.com/alexwebr/salsa20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using OpenSSL in your application, [version 1.1.0 has the ChaCha20 cipher](https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-1.1.0-notes.html), which is a newer, improved Salsa20 variant designed by the same author (Daniel J. Bernstein).  So I would consider using that.

If you're not using OpenSSL already, you might want to consider [NaCl](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/) or [Sodium](https://blog.opendns.com/2013/03/06/announcing-sodium-a-new-cryptographic-library/) instead, which are much easier to use safely.  For example, they focus on providing high-level public-key AEADs (authenticated encryption with associated data) instead of just low-level crypto primitives like stream ciphers and MACs.  These libraries use Salsa20 internally.

Comment: Where exactly ? I have hard time to find out, It's for encrypting files (coded in C/C++), I'm looking toward OpenSSL has my application already use a lots of their implementations, I also don't find any example. This is "ChaCha20_ctr32" ?

Comment: This is a crazy shit, only shitty result appear on google how come I can find properly implemented RC4 implementation everywhere but not for chacha